# Logstash create a new index every day

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I use elk for logging in asp.net app. But, I see in kibana that logstash create new index every day, for example logstash-2019-04-26, logstash-2019-04-27, logstash-2019-04-28. How to make was a single index? 
If this important, elk run in docker on vps server and code for setup logging:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://my_server:9200"))
    {
        ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.SetBasicAuthentication(username, password);
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a static index name in the logstash output plugin elasticsearch, with the [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index) option, replacing  `"logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"` by any static name.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide the index name in the output configuration. Example:

```
output {
amazon_es {
 hosts => ["vpc-xxx-es-yyy.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
 region => "us-east-1"
 aws_access_key_id => '<KEY>'
 aws_secret_access_key => '<SECRETKEY>'
 index => "indexnamestatic"
 }
}
```